# Postgres Query timediff on sequentials days

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have this type of records:
[image]

I need to compute the time difference beetween arrival and departure, also considering the case departure will be the next day, like Car 5 above example.
What could be an approach to do so?
Many thanks

###UPDATE
Unintentionally I did put a wrong data (changing months instead days), pls see updated ones

Comment: How it should be calculated in case of car 5

Comment: In case of car 5 I must consider 11/06/2019 12:14 - 11/05/2019 21:55 so 14:19 hr

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name cause care won't move before mindnight and depart next day

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's normal

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess this must record some kind of parking maybe? So it arrives at a spot and departs later again.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  You don't need to be Doc Brown to make this happen.  This table's arrivals and departures can be from the perspective of a fleet manager for a rental agency or a motor pool, or a service operation like a car wash or gas station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
with span_days as (
  select car, 
         arrival,
         coalesce(
           departure,
           lead(departure) over (partition by car 
                                     order by coalesce(arrival, departure))
         ) as departure 
    from car_arrive_depart
)
select car, arrival, departure, 
       departure - arrival as time_diff
  from span_days
 where arrival is not null;
```

This does not address how to deal with cars that are still departed at the time of the query, and it does extend beyond only the next day.

Comment: thx @mike, but how can u catch days sequence? I think it should include a concept of max(arrival), max(departure) = null

Comment: The sequence is handled by the `order by coalesce(arrival, departure)` in the window for `lead(departure)`.  Assuming that you never have overlapping time records for a `car`, this takes care of the sequence for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a always an arrival time for every departure of car. You can  try below query:

```
select 
*, 
case
when arrival is not null and departure is not null then departure-arrival
when arrival is null and departure is not null  and car=lag(car) over (order by car,arrival nulls last) then 
departure - lag(arrival) over (order by car,arrival nulls last)
end
from test
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2d47fa73fbd4b9bdc169d0a31c614e92)

Comment: Try to change dataset and it doesn't seems to work https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=930af3ba19f8d1791845606115e871e7

Comment: @user3925023 Can you explain what is not working, so that I can fix.

Comment: if you look to the link, last record calculation shows 00:02: this is wrong as car departure id after 2 days

Comment: Okzz. Corrected